# Year pick from vuejs date picker vue-date-pick

Tags: vue.js

Hi  i want to pick year in vue-date-pick

```
 <date-pick 
   v-model="award.date"
   :allowed-dates="allowedYears"
   type="year"
  >
  </date-pick>

 allowedYears: date => {
   return parseInt(date, 10) % 2 === 0;
  },
```

[image]

https://dbrekalo.github.io/vue-date-pick/

Comment: Your question could use a question.  Can you describe your problem more fully?

Comment: actually i want to use  vue-date-pick as a year selector but type =year doesn't change to year picker

Comment: I think you'd be better off using a different widget to select years -- something like a drop down menu or other integer input method would be more intuitive to the user.

Comment: okay thank you  . then i will try with dropdown.